# how to fix ubuntu 19.10 booting monitor to power saver mode

Tags: dual-boot, 19.10

I have dual booted windows with Ubuntu, and have recently upgraded from 19.0.4. As soon as the upgrade was complete, whenever I tried to boot Ubuntu from grub, my VGA monitor instantly went to power saver mode. It worked fine on previous versions.

I can boot up Windows just fine, any solutions?

Comment: @K7AAY A)I have a single monitor B) Desktop PC

Comment: @K7AAY Sorry for the late reply, I use VGA